# Can't recover mysql server

Tags: mysql, innodb, recovery

I have a really big problem with my database:

There was an electrical failure, a hard drive got damaged, whenever I tried to start the mysql server I got the error "I/O ERROR", I found that the ibdata1 file was corrupted.

I ran the `mysqld_safe --innodb_force_recovery=6` command wich seemed to have done something, but now when I try to start the server, it gives me this error:

```
2018-01-26 13:59:08 0 [Note] Binlog end
180126 13:59:08 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/demo11.pid ended
180126 14:08:45 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
2018-01-26 14:09:01 0 [Warning] Failed to normalize the argument for --secure-file-priv.
2018-01-26 14:09:01 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-01-26 14:09:01 0 [Note] Binlog end
180126 14:09:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/demo11.pid ended
```

I tried commenting the line where the secure-file-priv option is in my.cnf file but the error just keeps apearing and I really want to know if my data is still in there.

I also tried to copy my entire mysql directory into another server but it also wouldn't load, I'm really freaking out right now.

Comment: which MySQL version are you using?
after setting innodb_force_recovery=6 the error is the same? (--secure-file-priv)

Comment: Excuse me for my late answer, the setting innodb_force_recovery=6 gave me that error, before it, the error was code 5 I/O error, due to the damaged hard drive.
The actual server version is mysql5.7.
I've managed to remove the --secure-file-priv by modifing my.cnf (turns out the server has 5 diferent my.cnf and i was editing the wrong one), but this has caused a new error to rise.
I've also managed to salvage my data and i'm considering the idea of reinstalling the server

Comment: This is [the error's](https://pastebin.com/Q2SfAEZ6) log

Comment: From the error log output it seems like you're trying to start a MySQL version 5.6.33. If the data files were created with version 5.7, this could be the cause of the error.

Can you see all the required files inside de datadir? 
(it is required to have ibdata file, iblogfile, one folder for each database, inside each folder you should have one .frm file and .ibd file for each table.)

Comment: I have an ib_logilfe0 ib_logfile1 and ibdata1 (wich i assume is corrupted)